# Why can't I use straight paths in defining curves in the hobby library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

In the **hobby** library in Tikz I can define curves more or less like I can define them in Metapost, like so:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1.21,2.4598) coordinate (z1);
\draw (0.4820,2.1281) coordinate (z2);
\draw (-0.8821,0.9569) coordinate (z3);
\draw (-2.6476,-0.2303) coordinate (z4);
\draw (-2.4570,-1.1470) coordinate (z5);
\draw (-4.33,-1.77) coordinate (z6);


\draw  (z1)  to [ curve through ={(z2)..(z3)..(z4)..(z5)}] (z6); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this works, but why doesn't this following command work ?

```
\draw  (z1)  to [ curve through ={(z2)..(z3)--(z4)..(z5)}] (z6);
```

By the hobby library manual it should.

Worse yet, apparently I can use the following comand to make this work:

```
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{hobby}

 \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut ]
    
    
    \draw (1.21,2.4598) coordinate (z1);
    \draw (0.4820,2.1281) coordinate (z2);
    \draw (-0.8821,0.9569) coordinate (z3);
    \draw (-2.6476,-0.2303) coordinate (z4);
    \draw (-2.4570,-1.1470) coordinate (z5);
    \draw (-4.33,-1.77) coordinate (z6);

    \draw  (z1)..(z2)..(z3)--(z4)..(z5)..(z6);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't solve my problem, I am trying to use the program TikzEdt to speed my personal project to make a font, and the WYSIWYG mode in TikzEdt is very helpful, but the:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut ]
```

command seems to break its WYSIWYG editing mode.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: The `curve through` syntax runs the algorithm once on the supplied points.  The syntax `A .. B .. C -- D .. E .. F` runs the algorithm twice, once on `A .. B .. C` and `D .. E .. F` and there's a line between them. So to use the `curve through` syntax in the latter case you should write `\draw (z1) to[curve through={(z2)}] (z3) -- (z4) to[curve through={(z5)}] (z6);`. Also, you can put the `use Hobby shortcut` directly on the `\draw` command if it causes problems on the tikzpicture.  Also, where in the manual do you get that the `curve through` should work with `--`?

Comment: I thought a sentence in the manual implied that it could.

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you could tell me which sentence that was as I evidently need to rephrase it to make it clearer.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't perceive that I was talking to the person that wrote the manual. When in the manual it is written that "The purpose of allowing the dots is tomake it simpler to switch between the to path method and the short cut method (described in Section 2.2)", I thought that it meant that the A -- B -- C would also translate backwards into the to path method.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at that and see if I can make it clearer.  More importantly, did any of my suggestions help you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, the method of interrupting the to[curve through before the -- worked nicely.

Comment: That's great.  I've posted an answer along those lines, then, to lift this off the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curve through` notation was designed to *just* apply Hobby's algorithm on the points so it wasn't meant as a full path construction kit.  Thus

```
(a) to[curve through={(b) (c) (d)}] (e)
```

and

```
(a) .. (b) .. (c) .. (d) .. (e)
```

are meant to be the same.  Allowing `..` between the coordinates in the `curve through` is to make it easy to switch between the two, but they are actually NOPs in the `curve through` syntax.  So if `use Hobby shortcut` proves problematic, one could take the line above and simply change it to

```
(a) to[curve through={(b) .. (c) .. (d)}] (e)
```

thus saving a bit of editing.

The `curve through` version of

```
(a) .. (b) .. (c) -- (d) .. (e) .. (f)
```

is thus

```
(a) to[curve through={(b)}] (c) -- (d) to[curve through={(e)}] (f)
```

That is, each separate section needs to be replaced by `curve through`.

A working version of your code is thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583913/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1.21,2.4598) coordinate (z1);
\draw (0.4820,2.1281) coordinate (z2);
\draw (-0.8821,0.9569) coordinate (z3);
\draw (-2.6476,-0.2303) coordinate (z4);
\draw (-2.4570,-1.1470) coordinate (z5);
\draw (-4.33,-1.77) coordinate (z6);


\draw  (z1)  to [ curve through ={(z2)} ] (z3) -- (z4) to[curve through={(z5)}] (z6); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```